# java, json, align the start date and end date in each object

Tags: java

I want to compare the dates for each objects in the price object and make sure that the dates are not overlapping nor have gaps in between. In the following json, the dates are correct. When you read the first object, the last object, and the second object, you will see that the dates are aligned. Is there an algorithm that can help be accomplish this?

```
  "prices": [
        {
            "effectiveFrom": "", 
            "effectiveUntil": "2015-12-01T05:00:00.00Z", 
            "priceAmount": 11,
        }, 
        {
            "effectiveFrom": "2016-01-01T05:00:00.00Z", 
            "effectiveUntil": "", 
            "priceAmount": 11,
        }, 
        {
            "effectiveFrom": "2015-12-01T05:00:00.00Z", 
            "effectiveUntil": "2016-01-01T05:00:00.00Z", 
            "priceAmount": 5,
        }
```

Right now, I am checking index by index but this is not ideal because I can have more then 3 objects and then the logic will be messed up...

```
        if (i==0)
        {
            if (!endDate.equals(promoStartDate)) correctDates = false;
        }
        //after promotion ends
        if (i==1)
        {
            if (!startDate.equals(promoEndDate)) correctDates = false;
        }
        //during promotion period
        if (i==2)
        {
            if (!startDate.equals(promoStartDate) && !endDate.equals(promoEndDate)) correctDates = false;

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to sort all objects by startdate and then iterate throw them and check if enddate of one object equals startdate of the next.

In pseudo code:

```
prices = sort(...);
for (i = 0; i < prices.size()-1; i++) {
    if (prices[i].enddate != prices[i+1].startdate) return false;
}
return true;
```

Comment: what would be the most efficient way to sort? i think i need to sort the index

Comment: Suppposing you have a list of Price objects, you can use Collections.sort() with a custom Comparator<Price> that returns the result of comparing the startDate of two prices (make sure to handle cases where startDate is null).